# how many ways to arrange $3$ people to a circular table which has $6$ seats?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

As the title, how can I solve this problem?

Should I use combination with repitition or something else different?

Any help would be appreciated

---

3 people are distinguish. Below here is an example of symmetry situation which only consider as 1 way

[image]

but this situation is 2 ways

[image]

Comment: When do you say that two arrangements are identical?

Comment: @Gribouillis when those 2 arrangements are symmetry

Comment: @Becker: In which way could they be symmetrical. Given the symmetrical nature of a circle you could potentially add in more than one symmetry identification rule. For instance, does clockwise, anti-clockwise become identified via a reflection?

Comment: @String please see my edited post

Comment: @Becker: What about rotations then? Is $[p_1,p_2,p_3,0,0,0]\sim[0,p_1,p_2,p_3,0,0]$?

Comment: @String yes, it just consider as 1 way

Comment: @Becker: That clears it up. Griboullis will take it from here :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the rotation invariance, person $p_1$ can sit anywhere. Then $p_2$ can be one seat away from $p_1$, or two or three. Due to symmetry invariance, we can suppose that it is to the right of $p_1$. For each of these 3 options, person $p_3$ has 4 possible seats, but in the case where $p_2$ is 3 seats away from $p_1$, the positions of $p_3$ come in symmetric pairs. Hence there are $2\times 4 + 2 = 10$  ways to arrange the 3 people.

Comment: nice approach. tks for your help!